# How to correctly store original value from masked textbox to another textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, masking

I wanted to mimic the way password fields are hidden/shown by clicking an eye icon. The difference is that my input shouldn't be completely hidden and instead of the usual asterisk(*) symbol on password fields, the characters should be changed to 'x'. The format should be like Rxxxx4921 wherein the first character is shown, the next four characters are hidden, and the rest afterwards are normally shown.
I have two textboxes. One is where the original text should appear and the other one should show the masked text.
Reason for this is to show the unmasked textbox if 'show' is chosen and show the masked textbox if 'hide' is chosen.

My current code correctly masks the text when I input something on the unmasked textbox. However, when I try to input something inside the masked textbox, it will get the 'x' characters.

```
<input type="text" name="masknumber" maxlength="9">
<input type="text" name="number" maxlength="9">


  $("input[name='masknumber']").on("keyup", function() {
  $("input[name='number']").val(destroyMask(this.value));
  this.value = createMask($("input[name='number']").val());
})
  $("input[name='number']").on("keyup", function() {
  $("input[name='masknumber']").val(destroyMask(this.value));
  $("input[name='masknumber']").val(createMask($("input[name='number']").val()));
    })
$(document).ready(function() {
  var firstpart = "";
})

function createMask(string) {
  console.log(string)
  var len = string.length;
  if (len == 1)
    firstpart = string;
  var stars = len > 1 ? len > 2 ? len > 3 ? len > 4 ? firstpart + 'XXXX' :     firstpart + 'XXX' : firstpart + 'XX' : firstpart + 'X' : firstpart,
    result = stars + string.substring(5);
  return result;
}

function destroyMask(string) {
  console.log(string)
  //return string.replace(/\D/g,'').substring(0, 8);
  return string;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0dj8t6ga/

How do you successfully store the original value to the unmasked textbox? What if the user inserts a character in between the string, what should be added to the code to deal on that matter as well?

Comment: Have you considered using a masking library instead? There are a handful of good jQuery plugins that allow you to mask an input and still access the raw/unmasked value. If not, you'll have to store the unmasked value somehow. Perhaps an additional property on the input called `rawvalue` that gets the updated value *before* you mask it.

Comment: @TylerRoper Can inputmask do what I desired?